# How to fix Scanner class taking an extra blank input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sumAverageUsingArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * LargestValue
     */
    final int LENGTH = 5;
    int[] values = new int[LENGTH];
    int currentSize = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter values and Q to Quit");

    while (sc.hasNextInt() && currentSize < values.length) {
        values[currentSize] = sc.nextInt();
        currentSize++;
    }

    sc.close();
    int largest = values[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < currentSize; i++) {

        if (values[i] > largest) {

            largest = values[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("Largest is : %d", largest);
}
```

Expected:
5,4,3,2,1

Largest is : 5

Actual:
6,5,4,3,2,1

Largest is : 6

Scanner class takes an extra input which has no effect on the behavior of the program, how to fix it?

Comment: Is your input comma separated or space separated? Because in your example you use comma's, but your code will not work properly if that is the input you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
while (sc.hasNextInt() && currentSize < values.length) {
```

by

```
while (currentSize < values.length && sc.hasNextInt()) {
```

`hasNextInt()` is forced to block until you enter something to know if... there is a next int or not. If you enter an int, it can return true. If you enter something else, it can return false. If you don't enter enything, it needs to wait until you enter something to know what to return.